# SmtpClient - Attachments occasionally 0 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments, smtpclient, memorystream

I have a C# application that uses SmtpClient to send emails. Emails all appear to be being delivered fine however when sending emails with attachments, periodically the attachment will be 0 bytes.

I'm using MemoryStream to write the attachment and the stream cursor is explicitly set to the start of the stream.

I'm using gmails smtp server to send the mail. The troubling part is sometimes attachments send fine and other times they have 0 bytes. I haven't been able to find any consistent pattern when testing either. I'll manually send 5 emails in secession all to the same email address all with the same attachment. Randomly only 1 or 2 of the email contain the attachment well the others are all 0 bytes.

Any guess? Here's the snippet of my code where I create and send the mail.

```
private void DispatchSmtpAsync(MessagePayload payload, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        foreach (EmailAddress recipient in payload.To)
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient.Email, recipient.Name));
        foreach (EmailAddress recipient in payload.Cc)
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(recipient.Email, recipient.Name));
        foreach (EmailAddress recipient in payload.Bcc)
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(recipient.Email, recipient.Name));

        foreach (MyApp.Services.Email.Common.Models.Attachment attachment in payload.Content.Attachments)
        {
            byte[] content = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Content);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, attachment.Name, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(attachment.Name)));
        }

        message.From = new MailAddress(payload.From.Email, payload.From.Name);
        message.Body = payload.Content.Html;
        message.Subject = payload.Content.Subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.Host = unitOfWork.SystemSettingRepository.GetValue<string>(SystemSettingName.SmtpHost);
        client.Port = unitOfWork.SystemSettingRepository.GetValue<int>(SystemSettingName.SmtpPort);
        client.EnableSsl = unitOfWork.SystemSettingRepository.GetValue<bool>(SystemSettingName.SmtpSsl);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(unitOfWork.SystemSettingRepository.GetValue<string>(SystemSettingName.SmtpUsername),
                unitOfWork.SystemSettingRepository.GetValue<string>(SystemSettingName.SmtpPassword));

            client.SendAsync(message, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding logging / metrics for when `content.Length` is 0.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You could just do `var stream = new MemoryStream(content);`...

Comment: Try to locate the line which drops the attachment. `Trace.Write` is helpful for this purpose.

Comment: Can't be this some threading issue by any chance? Don't you share your SmtpClient instance between multiple threads? However, I'd drop SmtpClient (had many issues with that) and [use MailKit instead](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/MailKit-MimeKit-Official).

Comment: Maybe test, if content.Length == 0 before adding the attachment.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the feedback. Still no solution. I've tried tracing the file and adding a condition for content.Length == 0 but no luck. 

Must have something to do with async and multiple threads, but I haven't had any luck to get this to work consistently.  

I went back synchronous with SmtpClient.Send and everything works fine...